# Running firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, x11

So I have a server which I always log into via ssh. I am using selenium to scrape a website and am attempting to get firefox running via command line. When I run firefox, I get the following error:

```
    gksu ./firefox <br>**
    No protocol specified

   (gksu:28027): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

I have my display variable set to :0, do I need to run the x11 server? just generally confused any feedback appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

> I have my display variable set to :0, do I need to run the x11 server?

Yes!

Telling it to use DISPLAY :0 when DISPLAY :0 doesn't exist isn't going to work. The X11 server provides the display that the app connects to in order to show the GUI.

Comment: So I ssh into the server and start up x11 by running sudo startx &. Then everything seems to start nicely. But when I run firefox I then still get the same error messages (no protocol specified...) ideas?